# Session not removed from SessionRegistry upon logout when using primepush (p:socket) on Weblogic 12c

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, weblogic, atmosphere

I have a spring application (spring 4) and using primefaces (version 5.1) for the UI. I've a page where i use p:socket only to get updates from the server:

```
<p:socket transport="sse" channel="#{backingBean.refreshChannel}" autoConnect="true">
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="fplUpdateDialogId" event="message" oncomplete="PF('fplUpdateDialog').show()"/>
</p:socket>
```

I use tomcat 7 for local development and weblogic 12c for production deployment. Message push to the client works in both application server very well.

The problem here is that the session is not removed from the session registry when the user logs out himself via clicking on the logout button. But this issue occurs only in weblogic. On tomcat it is just fine.

If I remove the p:socket from the page, it works fine. So this must be related to weblogic-primefaces-atmosphere framework triangle (primefaces uses atmosphere framework for pushing messages to the client).

I have debugged and saw that session.invalidate() is being called definitely in the SecurityContextLogoutHandler class (using spring security 3.2.7). Upon session.invalidate(), HttpSessionEventPublisher class, a HttpSessionListener, is informed via calling the sessionDestroyed method. Then HttpSessionEventPublisher publishes HttpSessionDestroyedEvent in the application context. Later the session is removed from the session registry.

On weblogic, even the session.invalidate() is being called, the HttpSessionEventPublisher is not informed about session destroy event. From this point on, i have no clue why. Is this event never fired? If fired, what happened to it? I've searched for hours but could not find a useful hint.